# Special Characters in SQL

Tags: sql-server, ascii, special-characters

I am working on a project in which bulk data is being uploaded from a Excel file in my SQL table, this data include mostly the space characters which I am not able to replace by Ltrim Rtrim. 
I search for this special character Ascii, Sometimes it shows it ascii 160 sometimes 9. 
I also tried with Replace function but replaces the spaces between the string which is not my requirement.

Can any one help me out of this

Comment: Question is not clear

Comment: Try this, if this helps. http://improvingsoftware.com/2011/03/21/replacing-multiple-spaces-in-a-string-with-a-single-space-in-sql/

Comment: 160 is nonbreaking space (html variant) and 9 is tab character. What problems causes replacing these characters with spaces and trimming afterwards? Or - could you replace these chars after inserting into SQL?

Comment: Please include sample data and expected output.

Comment: How are you loading that data?

Comment: Hi arvo, you are right but problem is these spaces can be occur any where in the string may be leading,trailing or in between

Comment: Hi JotaBe, I am inserting data from .Net application using Bulk Upload

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question it is hard to know what you want the end result to be.

If you want to remove the ASCII 160 & 9, then it would be as simple as:

```
UPDATE tablename
   SET fieldname = REPLACE(REPLACE(fieldname, CHAR(160), ''), CHAR(9), '')
```

If you are wanting something else, please be specific in the question and provide a few samples of the data.